# SQL Case statement with multi left outer joins

Tags: sql, join, case

Is it possible to do case statements and to left outer joins like I am doing below?  I put comments on what I am trying to achieve.

```
SELECT
    eventGame.Id,
    eventGame.[Type] AS GameType
FROM GrassrootsHoops.EventGame eventGame
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
    divisionGameTeamResult.Id,
    divisionGameTeamResult.GameId,
    COALESCE(divisionPool.Name, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Name) AS DivisionPoolName
FROM GrassrootsHoops.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult
LEFT OUTER JOIN

-- CASE eventGame.[Type] = 1 THEN

GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPoolGame divisionTeamPoolGame
    ON divisionTeamPoolGame.Id = divisionGameTeamResult.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoopS.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPool
    ON divisionTeamPool.Id = divisionTeamPoolGame.DivisionTeamPoolId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPool
    ON divisionPool.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionPoolId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPoolSettings divisionPoolSettings
    ON divisionPool.Id = divisionPoolSettings.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeam
    ON divisionTeam.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team team
    ON team.Id = divisionTeam.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN

-- CASE eventGame.[Type] = 2 THEN

GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketGameParticipant
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = divisionGameTeamResult.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart
    ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeam divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamBracket
    ON divisionTeamBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam.DivisionTeamId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team teamBracket
    ON teamBracket.Id = divisionTeamBracket.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracket
    ON divisionBracketParticipantBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket
    ON divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantBracket.DivisionBracketId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPool divisionBracketGameParticipantPool
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantPool.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPoolBracket
    ON divisionPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantPool.DivisionPoolId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeamPool divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPoolBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool.DivisionTeamPoolId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionPoolId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionTeamId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team teamPoolTeamBracket
    ON teamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id
WHERE divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam = 1) homeTeam
    ON homeTeam.GameId = eventGame.GameId
```

Comment: Which table does alias 'game' belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do case statements with outer joins. I think you can do what you want, though by using a UNION. Here's an example using a simpler schema where we are doing two separate joins based on the type of game.

```
  SELECT
    Game.Id,
    PoolResult.Score
  FROM
    Game
  JOIN PoolResult
    ON PoolResult.GameId = Game.Id
  WHERE
    Game.GameType = 1
UNION
  SELECT
    Game.Id,
    BracketResult.Score
  FROM
    Game
  JOIN BracketResult
    ON BracketResult.GameId = Game.Id
  WHERE
    Game.GameType = 2
```

([Here's a working version at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9822/1))

For your query, you just want to write two completely separate queries one for each type of game. Once you have that working for each separate query, just stick a UNION in between them and the results will be concatenated together. Here's your query modified to use a UNION. I don't have an easy way to check it for errors, so there's probably some minor errors

```
  SELECT
    divisionGameTeamResult.Id,
    eventGame.[Type] AS GameType
  FROM
    GrassrootsHoops.EventGame eventGame
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult
    ON (divisionGameTeamResult.GameId = eventGame.GameId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPoolGame divisionTeamPoolGame
    ON divisionTeamPoolGame.Id = divisionGameTeamResult.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoopS.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPool
    ON divisionTeamPool.Id = divisionTeamPoolGame.DivisionTeamPoolId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPool
    ON divisionPool.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionPoolId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPoolSettings divisionPoolSettings
    ON divisionPool.Id = divisionPoolSettings.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeam
    ON divisionTeam.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team team
    ON team.Id = divisionTeam.Id
  WHERE
    divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam = 1
  AND
    eventGame.[Type] = 1
UNION
  SELECT
    divisionGameTeamResult.Id,
    eventGame.[Type] AS GameType
  FROM
    GrassrootsHoops.EventGame eventGame
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult
    ON (divisionGameTeamResult.GameId = eventGame.GameId)
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketGameParticipant
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = divisionGameTeamResult.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart
    ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeam divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamBracket
    ON divisionTeamBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantTeam.DivisionTeamId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team teamBracket
    ON teamBracket.Id = divisionTeamBracket.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracket
    ON divisionBracketParticipantBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket
    ON divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantBracket.DivisionBracketId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPool divisionBracketGameParticipantPool
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantPool.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPoolBracket
    ON divisionPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantPool.DivisionPoolId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeamPool divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool
    ON divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipant.Id
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPoolBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketGameParticipantTeamPool.DivisionTeamPoolId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionPoolId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket
    ON divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionTeamId
  JOIN GrassrootsHoops.Team teamPoolTeamBracket
    ON teamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id
  WHERE
    divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam = 1
  AND
    eventGame.[Type] = 1
```

Comment: I assume in this approach the second select in the Union would never take place if Type = 2? and vice versa.  I am just trying to cut down on the joints going on.

Comment: With a UNION it's sort of the same as running both SQL queries separately and then concatenating them. In my example, the the first select query has a WHERE that limits it to Type = 1 and the second select query has a where that limits it to Type = 2. That means the first one will only return rows for games where Type = 1 and the second one will only return rows for games where Type = 2.

Comment: Wont work because eventGame is outside of the inner query and could not be bound.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a simpler example that explains what I mean better. I also had a go at redoing your original query using a UNION so that you can try and just run it.